# connect Modelica with arduino by firmata

Tags: arduino, modelica, firmata

I would like to connect my arduino with modelica by using the firmataprotokoll and the arduinolibrary.
But the compilation always fails because of the error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'ModelicaFirmata.lib'

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Without knowing any of the mentioned devices/technology/... A LINK error usually means that a .dll (of .lib in this case) cannot be found. So the file `ModelicaFirmata.lib` does either not exists at the expected location or the processs that needs it does not have a specified location. To fix it, try to analyze logs so that you know where it is looking for it

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by a wrong version of the Modelica-Arduino-Library. Instead of downloading the code I should have downloaded the latest release on github.

In addition it is important to choose the right compiler in Modelica (Visual Studio 2015).